# Server Side Auto Suggest Not filtering values

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a suggestion box, where it perfectly works fine when there is a client-side source binding (here eg: availableTags)

```
$(function () {
    var availableTags = [
        "ActionScript",
        "AppleScript",
        "Asp",
        "BASIC",
        "C",
        "C++",
        "Clojure",
        "COBOL",
        "ColdFusion",
        "Erlang",
        "Fortran",
        "Groovy",
        "Haskell",
        "Java",
        "JavaScript",
        "Lisp",
        "Perl",
        "PHP",
        "Python",
        "Ruby",
        "Scala",
        "Scheme"];
    $("#tags").autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
    });


});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fwaq3dkz/28/

But when I change the source to the server side, it still lists the suggested values, but it won't filter the values which I entered in the suggestion box

```
$("#tags").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.getJSON('/User/GetUsersJSONAsync', function (data) {
            var users = [];
            for (let key in data) {

                users.push(data[key].userPrincipalName);
            }
            response(users);
        });
    },    
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fwaq3dkz/31/

*PS: The above fiddle won't give any JSON reply because it is hitting an MVC controller in my code, which I can't use in fiddle, this is just for representational purpose only.*

Means, when I enter "A", it lists all the tags with "A" and "a" in the first case which is client-side source. 
But, it will not filter in the second case which is the server side source, instead, it will list everything.

Comment: Is this not a correct behavior? When you are moving the code to server side, then autocomplete plugin will load the data which is sent by server. Since, you should be sending the whole list so it is showing everything. There are possible solution here --- 1) Pass the search term to server so that server filters the list and returns which matches the filter criteria. 2) Fetch everything at client side and keep the array in memory at client side. Then assign it to $("#tags") element for autocomplete to work.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion i made it work

Answer (score 0):

Fixed in by adding a paramter to severside , Thank for hints by @user1672994

> var textInputObj = { textValue: $("#search").val() };

```
// Sets up the multicolumn autocomplete widget.
$("#search").mcautocomplete({
    // These next two options are what this plugin adds to the autocomplete widget.
    showHeader: false,
    columns: columns,   
    source: function (request, response) {

        var textInputObj = { textValue: $("#search").val() };

        $.getJSON('/User/GetUsersJSONAsync', textInputObj, function (data) {
            var users = [];

            for (let key in data) {
                   users.push(new Array(data[key].surname ? data[key].surname : "Blank", data[key].displayName, data[key].userPrincipalName));                 

            }          
            response(users);
        });
    },
```

Answer (score -1):

Possibly because this is happening asynchronously, have you tried setting the autocomplete after the JSON response has been returned? For example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON('/User/GetUsersJSONAsync', function (data) {
        var users = [];
        for (let key in data) {
            users.push(data[key].userPrincipalName);
        }
        $("#tags").autocomplete({
            source: users
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: $.getJSON('/User/GetUsersJSONAsync', function (data) {
    var users = [];
    for (let key in data)
        users.push(data[key].userPrincipalName);
    alert(data[key].userPrincipalName);
    $("#tags").autocomplete({
        source: users
    })
});

Comment: above code i put it in onReady, the code you have given me have syntax issues, no luck

Comment: Sorry, there was a missing `}`. I have updated the answer to correct the syntax issue, and wrapped this within `$(document).ready()`, this would be the best place to ensure the DOM is loaded before executing.

Comment: i checked the edited code, getJson is not hitting while in type in letters, is this possible to move as a ajax call?

Comment: controller is not hitting

Comment: $.ajax({
    url: '/User/UserInJSON',
    complete: function (data) {       
        var users = [];
    for (let key in data) {
        users.push(data[key].userPrincipalName);        
        }

        $("#tags").autocomplete({
            source: users
        });
    }
});

Comment: So it does not seem that it is running asynchronously is the issue - sorry I thought this would be worth a try at least.